# how to we make $y$ the subject in $x=y-y^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> how to we make $y$ the subject in $x=y-y^2$

I factorised $y(1-y) = x$

But now I will still have $y$ on both sides $y= \frac{x}{1-y}$

Comment: Why not solve the quadratic equation $y^2-y+x=0$ with $y=\ldots$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try completing the square

$$y^2-y=-x$$

$$y^2-y+\frac{1}{4}=x+\frac{1}{4}$$

$$\left(y-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2=x+\frac{1}{4}$$

Can you continue?

Comment: Someone who can solve complicated integrals and has two gold batches should not be able to continue with a quadratic equation? What am I missing?

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: "Can you continue?"

Comment: @DietrichBurde maybe your point about integrals is fine, but having gold badges has got nothing to do with mathematical ability. If you see the badges, you’ll notice that both of them are for “Questions with >10k views” and both questions are fairly elementary, i.e. listing of primes, and some financial math.

Comment: There was no intention to be disrespectful or condescending to the poster--I just tried to  be helpful by getting them started with the problem. Idk why you're acting like I slighted him in some way.

Comment: @DietrichBurde people can often plug-and-chug a lot of formulas but that doesn't mean they have any mathematical ability or understanding. Engineers provide a wealth of examples along these lines.

Comment: I was unpolite to you because you were implying I was being rude to OP by asking "can you continue"

Comment: @DietrichBurde are you Hans Niemann by any chance? XD